# Javascript how to make an image appear based on a function's output

Tags: javascript, image, function

I'm trying to create some code so that an image appears once certain text is displayed.

My first function generates a random word from an array once a button is clicked:

```
<script>
var fruits2 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function myFunction4()
 {
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = fruits2[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
}
</script>
```

From this I've tried the following, which is incorrect and to be honest I'm not sure where to start

```
<script>
VAR D =myFunction4();

{

if (D ="Orange")
{document.write("<IMG SRC ='test.png'>";}
}
<script>
```

So from the above, I've generated random words, i.e Orange and from this word I'd like to display an image of an Orange, or Apple if the word generated was Apple.

Any help would be much appreciated! The site im trying to create isn't based on fruits, these have just been used to simplify things

Comment: It should be `var`, not `VAR`.

Comment: And it should be `==` or `===` not `=`

Answer (score 0):

Your function myFunction4 have to return a value.

```
    function myFunction4()
      {
          var randomFruit= fruits2[Math.floor(Math.random()*fruits2.lenght)];
          document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = randomFruit;
          return randomFruit


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Your function must return something:

```
var fruits2 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function myFunction4() {
   return fruits2[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
}
```

then you can show the image:

```
var d = myFunction4();
if (d == "Orange") {
    document.write("<img src='test.png'/>");
}
```

Comment: Fixed! I've missed it! Thanks